# c# how can I update just one line text in richtextbox?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

how can I update just one line text in richtextbox?

```
String[] lines = richTextBox8.Lines;
lines[2] += " ";
richTextBox8.Lines = lines;
```

I am using this code part for update second line of richtextbox but it scans all my richtextbox lines and it takes many times.

so I want to update line text for 1 line.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that you **must never** touch the `Text` or the `Lines` directly or all previous formatting gets messed up.

Here is a function that will solve the problem without messing up the formatting:

```
void changeLine(RichTextBox RTB, int line, string text)
{
    int s1 = RTB.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);
    int s2 = line < RTB.Lines.Count() - 1 ?
              RTB.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line+1) - 1 : 
              RTB.Text.Length;        
    RTB.Select(s1, s2 - s1);
    RTB.SelectedText = text;
}
```

Note the in  C# the numbering is zero beased, so to change the 1st line you call `changeLine(yourrichTextBox, 0, yourNewText);`

To only modify (not replace) the line you can simply access the `Lines` property; just make sure never to **change** it!

So to add a blank to the 2nd line you can write:

```
changeLine(yourrichTextBox, 1, yourrichTextBox.Lines[1] + " ");
```

Comment: Thanks I am using modfy the line but I am living issue with the last line of richtextbox :/

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Sorry, I have updated the answer. Does it work now for you?

Comment: I'd like to add, that this code will work correctly only in case if you disable word wrapping.