# C# cmd output progress (%) one line

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd, richtextbox, progress

I'm working on a `cmd` output to `RichTextBox`.
Is there any way to merge/join all the progress (%) into a single line of the `RichTextBox`? Instead of creating a line for each %. I would like it to be like `cmd` (except removing the blank lines as it is now).

```cs
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Execute1("Prtest.exe", " x mode2 C:\\input.iso C:\\output.iso");
});
}

private void Execute1(string filename, string cmdLine){
var fileName = filename;
var arguments = cmdLine;

var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = fileName;
info.Arguments = arguments;

info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;

using (var p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo = info;
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    p.OutputDataReceived += (s, o) =>
    {
        tConsoleOutput(o.Data);
    };
    p.ErrorDataReceived += (s, o) =>
    {
        tConsoleOutput(o.Data);
    };

    p.Start();
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    p.BeginErrorReadLine();
    p.WaitForExit();
}
}

public void tConsoleOutput(string text){
BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate ()
{
    rtConsole.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine);
    rtConsole.ScrollToCaret();
    //remove empty lines
    rtConsole.Text = Regex.Replace(rtConsole.Text, @"^\s*$(\n|\r|\r\n)", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
}));
}
```

Real `cmd.exe` output:

`Processing: 100%`

`Sectors: 43360`

`Completed.`

C# `RichTextBox` (rtConsole) output:

`Processing: 2%`
`Processing: 4%`
`Processing: 7%`
`Processing: 9%`
`Processing: 11%`
`Processing: 14%`
`Processing: 16%`
`Processing: 39%`
`Processing: 100%`
`Sectors: 43360`
`Completed.`

**UPDATE: Solved**

[image]

**Big Thanks @Jackdaw**

Comment: How the `rtConsole` is defined?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29445502/106159) for how to overwrite a line in a `RichTextBox`.

Comment: Hi @Jackdaw. Is not. It is a simple richtextbox component (default, no changes). I'm starting now in C# VS2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the method below:

```cs
static public void tConsoleOutput(RichTextBox rtb, string line)
{
    var pattern = @"^Processing: \d{1,3}%.*$";   
    if (!line.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine))
        line += Environment.NewLine;

    var isProcessing = Regex.Match(line, pattern).Success;

    rtb.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            var linesCount = rtb.Lines.Length;
            if (linesCount > 1 && isProcessing)
            {
                var last = rtb.Lines[linesCount - 2];
                if (Regex.Match(last, pattern).Success)
                {
                    var nlSize = Environment.NewLine.Length;
                    // Update latest line
                    var sIndex = rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(linesCount - nlSize);
                    var eIndex = sIndex + last.Length + nlSize;
                    rtb.Select(sIndex, eIndex - sIndex);
                    rtb.SelectedText = line;    
                    return;                                
                }                
            }
            rtb.AppendText(line);
        });
}
```

And seems like that:

[image]

Comment: Amazing, fantastic. Congratulations @Jackdaw you have excellent skills.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the code that you have written (or, if it's not yours, where it comes from) but I can tell you that the easiest way of doing this is the `\r` character, which resets your caret to the beginning of the line.

This means that you must make sure not to use `Console.WriteLine` but `Console.Write` instead.

An example:

```
Console.Write("00.00% Done");
Thread.Sleep(1500);
Console.Write("\r100.00% Done");
```